# How to prevent "Featured"appearing in the title tag of my K2 featured articles?

Tags: joomla-2.5, k2

I would like to remove the word "Featured" that appear every time I set an article as FEATURED in K2.

For example, if my article meta title is:

> This is my article

It changes to:

> This is My Article Featured

and I DON'T want this to happens, when I set the Featured state to my articles.

Thank you for your time and help, guys.

Comment: What template are you using? Can you modify your custom.css to hide the 'featured' png?

Comment: The alternative would be a template override, which isn't difficult.

Comment: I'm using Afterburner 2.. Can I really override meta tags with .css ?? I don't want to hide the featured ICON but the META TITLE TAG

Answer (score 2):

In K2 that is controlled by the "Item view options in category listings" or "Item view options" on the category or the item. The field is called "'Featured' notice (next to title)"